# how to parse data from a csv file into a container and search for 1 value and retrieve the rest of the values on its line in java

Tags: java, android, google-maps, csv

i am trying to read comma separated values from a text file which contains a postcode, latitude and longitude on each line and i want to parse this data and then access it when a user inputs a postcode to then find the lat and long on its corresponding line, which then the program takes the lat and long and finds the location on a map using the google maps api, however im having trouble.

this is where i read the file

```
    public void readFromFile() {

    BufferedReader read = null;
    String line;
    String fileName = "";
    String seperator = ",";


    try {

        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
        read  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        //read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

        while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
            postcodeCSV = line.split(seperator);
             postcode = postcodeCSV[0] ;


            line = read.readLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (read != null) read.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is my main file

```
  public String postcode ;
  public float latitude ;
  public float longitude ;

public String[] postcodeCSV;

EditText POSTCODE_et;
ImageButton FIND_ib;

private LatLng ADDRESS = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
private GoogleMap MAP_GM;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_address);

    POSTCODE_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.postcode_et);
    FIND_ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.find_ib);
    MAP_GM = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_gm)).getMap();

    readFromFile();


    FIND_ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (String s : postcodeCSV) {
                String Postcode_getter = POSTCODE_et.getText().toString();
                if (s == Postcode_getter) {
                    latitude = Float.parseFloat(postcodeCSV[1]);//postcodeCSV[1];
                    longitude = Float.parseFloat(postcodeCSV[2]);


                }

                CameraUpdate updateMap = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ADDRESS);
                MAP_GM.animateCamera(updateMap);
            }

        }

    });



}
```

Comment: Where are you having trouble ? I think you are looking for a `HashMap` as a data structure to store the PostCode as key & Lat Lon as value.

Comment: What does main file have to do with the parsing? --- Also, you're double-calling `read.readLine()` (on the `while` and at the end of the loop).

Comment: this is what i have so far but it is not working for some reason. @Sid i want to parse the text file so it holds each value and then search it and obtain the lat and long when the find button is clicked once it takes in the value of a postcode

Comment: @Andreas thats where i call the readfile function and it holds the find button to do the parsing once clicked. i read somewhere that calling read.readLine( ) at the end of the while will allow it to search for the next line.

Comment: @skandal _"parse the text file so **it** holds each value"_ .. when you parse a document, you need to parse the document into some data structure. Use a `HashMap` with your postCode as the key and lat long as value. Check [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm) demo.

Comment: @Sid i done this in c++ with a vector and it was fine but i cant seem to do so in java. is a HashMap the best data structure to use for this?

Comment: What is _best_ is subjective, a HashMap has an O(1) lookup, check out the linked article and read some more on it to see if it suits your performance needs.

Comment: @skandal A C++ [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) is a Java [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a

`Map<String, LatLon> postCodeMap = new HashMap<>();`

Where the Key is your postcode as a String and Value is a custom class LatLon as shown below:

```
public class LatLon{
   double latitude;
   double longitude;

   //getter & setters
   //constructor
}
```

To put a new Value

```
postCodeMap.put("55555", new LatLon(92.00,-32.75))
```

To Look Up a new Value:

```
LatLon latlon = postCodeMap.get("55555");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem stems from you overwriting the postcode and postcodeCSV for every other line.  The every other line part comes from you doing while(line = read.readLine()) and then 5 lines later calling line = read.readLine() again.

Here is what I would do:
A) Create a class called PostOffice with code, lat and long as the fields.

B) remove the second readLine()

C) For each line create a new postOffice

D) Add each new postOffice to a List of postOffices (which should be a field)

F) In your onClick, iterate through the postOffices and check for the user entered value such as

```
for(PostOffice po : postOffices)
{
  if(po.code == POSTCODE_et.getText().toString())
  {
    latitude = po.lat;
    longitude = po.lon;
  }
}
```